# Get values of elements from a certain section of XML

Tags: xml, xmlreader

My XmlReader goes through the XML looking for specific elements that I am looking for. The problem is that the one element I am needing exist in two different areas of the XML. My need for this attempt is obtaining the `j:RegisterActionDescriptionText` values from the `<RecordDocketingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:RecordDocketingMessage-4.0">` section and not from `<CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">` section of the XML.

XML Example:

```
  <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001" s:metadata="# Pages=2">
    <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Notices">Civil Coversheet</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:51.373476-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:54.813-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
    <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
      <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="63196854">6721      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
      <ecf:FilingPartyID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>49372</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:FilingPartyID>
      <ecf:SpecialHandlingInstructions />
    </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
    <ecf:DocumentRendition>
      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID>CCS.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
          <nc:BinaryBase64Object>Removed for security purposes</nc:BinaryBase64Object>
          <nc:BinarySizeValue>97426</nc:BinarySizeValue>
          <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>1</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
        </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
      </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
    </ecf:DocumentRendition>
  </FilingLeadDocument>
  <FilingConnectedDocument s:id="DOC00002" s:metadata="# Pages=1">
    <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="Other">Mortgage Claim Amount Worksheet</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">102</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:51.373476-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:54.813-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
    <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
      <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="63196975">1417      </j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
      <ecf:FilingPartyID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>49372</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:FilingPartyID>
    </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
    <ecf:DocumentRendition>
      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID>VRP.pdf</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00002">
         <nc:BinaryBase64Object>Removed for security purposes</nc:BinaryBase64Object>
         <nc:BinarySizeValue>61900</nc:BinarySizeValue>
          <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>2</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
        </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
      </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
    </ecf:DocumentRendition>
  </FilingConnectedDocument>



<ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00001">
    <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-03T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:51.373</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:54.813</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
    <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
    <nc:DocumentStatus>
      <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
    </nc:DocumentStatus>
    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
      <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="63196854">5583</j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
      <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00001" />
    </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
    <ecf:DocumentRendition>
      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="2" />
    </ecf:DocumentRendition>
  </ecf:ReviewedLeadDocument>
  <ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument s:id="REVIEWEDDOC00002">
    <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-03T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:51.373</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-09-02T13:30:54.813</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
    <nc:DocumentSequenceID>2</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
    <nc:DocumentStatus>
      <nc:StatusText>ACCEPTED</nc:StatusText>
    </nc:DocumentStatus>
    <ecf:DocumentMetadata>
      <j:RegisterActionDescriptionText s:id="63196975">10177</j:RegisterActionDescriptionText>
      <ecf:ParentDocumentReference s:ref="DOC00002" />
    </ecf:DocumentMetadata>
    <ecf:DocumentRendition>
      <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata s:metadata="1" />
    </ecf:DocumentRendition>
  </ecf:ReviewedConnectedDocument>
```

Current Code:

```
if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xr.Name == "j:RegisterActionDescriptionText")
  {
   eventCode = xr.ReadElementString();
    if (eventCode != null)
     {
      lbEventCode.Items.Add(eventCode);
     }
   }
```

Comment: First suggestion - replace XmlReader hard-coded one-way walking with normal XElement processing - so it will be much readable and simple to use. Reorganize code - here we see spaghetti from IO, hard-coded xml processing and GUI update/reading. Well formed code first and main step to solve any problem

Comment: @ФагимСадыков I am not following you on the response. This is kicked off by a button click event, creates a folder based on the file name and then reads the specific elements from the XML. This is an application currently in use and I've been tasked to make changes. I don't code like this ever. ;-) How would XElement make it better? Also, I need the `j:RegisterActionDescriptionText` value from  `ReviewedLeadDocument` and `ReviewedConnectedDocument`  instead of getting twice from `FilingLeadDocument`\`FilingConnectedDocument` and  `ReviewedLeadDocument` and `ReviewedConnectedDocument`

Comment: XElement allows you to organize code and validly collect required elements, and then update your files and interface. You post code with not renamed TextBox1 and ListBox1 but it's real code, so it seems you like to write code, but not think about how to organize and plan it. Any solution (even small) have Model which describes data structures and their relations (here it's BASE64 images and filenames) and have some supportive structures which must be implemented maximally independent - here it's "DeserializerFromXml" which (being implemented) could BUILD MODEL FROM XML FILE,

Comment: "Base64Storager" which can GET MODEL AND STORE IT TO DISC and "GuiIntermedate" which can PROVIDE BRIDGE FROM MODEL TO GUI.  Try to do your work more OOP and organized, use appropriate tools (XElement for deserializing for example) and all will be fine

Comment: I am completely clueless with the information you are posting. My post was in regards to isolate getting to a certain section of the XML instead of duplicating the information

Comment: @ФагимСадыков, `XElement` not a normal processing. This class usable only in .NET 3.5 and above. In `XElement` you will need to hard-code elements's names too as in `XmlReader`.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework you are using?

Comment: @Fabio I am using the 3.5 framework.

Comment: XElement is not a stream U can use it as indexed in-memory database  with clone/update/change facility, no any compare with XmlReader or XPathNavigator and far more faster and simple than XmlDocument. Who are using .NET 2.0 with ANY logical basis? It's great question why you are looking for help if u are so sure that all is well done )

Comment: @Fabio Can you provide any productive insight into my issue?

Comment: Use `XElement` class for getting values from different places of `XML` file  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx) or [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844374/how-to-read-a-specific-element-value-from-xelement-in-linq-to-xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844374/how-to-read-a-specific-element-value-from-xelement-in-linq-to-xml)

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for the links. I am able to get the values but my issue is that the value is listed twice for the same element name (but not always going to match up because the first time it is usually wrong and the second part where it is listed is the corrected one). I need to get the value in the second part of the XML instead of the first part.