# Accessing XElement with specific value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to save my battleship game to XML and so far it has gone pretty good. What I'm saving in the XML file is player names, coordinates for ships and misses.

The ID attribute for the ships is to know which ship coordinates makes a whole ship. Next up was marking each ship that it has been hit by adding an attribute to the correct element and I know what element to get by the value of it.

But I do not know how to get it. All I have found is how to get `XElement` by its `name` and all elements that has that name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Players>
  <Playerboard>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Ships>
      <ship id="1213">12_13</ship>
      <ship id="1213">12_14</ship>
      <ship id="1211">12_11</ship>
      <ship id="1211">12_12</ship>
    </Ships>
    <Misses>
      <Miss>3_9</Miss>
      <Miss>9_12</Miss>
      <Miss>10_12</Miss>
    </Misses>
  </Playerboard>
  <Computerboard>
    <Name>AI</Name>
    <Ships>
      <ship id="1010">10_10</ship>
      <ship id="1010">10_11</ship>
      <ship id="1010">10_12</ship>
      <ship id="1010">10_13</ship>
      <ship id="11">1_1</ship>
      <ship id="11">2_1</ship>
    </Ships> 
    <Misses>
      <Miss>0_2</Miss>
      <Miss>0_3</Miss>
      <Miss>1_3</Miss>
    </Misses>
  </Computerboard>
</Players>
```

this is as far as i've come with trying to get the correct element, which doesnt work. "k" in my example below is empty all the time.

```
XElement e = xelement.Element("Playerboard");
var ships = from s in e.Elements("Ships")            
                        where (string)s.Element("ship") == x + "_" +y
                        select s;

foreach (XElement k in ships) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

So for example I want to add an attribute to the ship with value 12_12, how do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Hopefully somebody a bit more knowledgeable in using C# to manage XML comes along and gives you an answer, but I might suggest adding `.ToString()` on `k` when writing it to the console? `Console.WriteLine(k.ToString());`

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844374/how-to-read-a-specific-element-value-from-xelement-in-linq-to-xml
also google how to use `XPath`

Comment: @kehrk: `Console.WriteLine` will do that for you.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe I'm missing something - if you're creating the XML yourself, why not create it complete in the first place? Why do you create it incomplete and then edit it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844374/how-to-read-a-specific-element-value-from-xelement-in-linq-to-xml only told me what i do not want do to. They access the element by the name of it, not its value.

and @vesan you are missing something yes. It is supposed to be a game of battleship with this xml file representing the state of the game. The attribute i want to add is added when a ship is hit. Thats why i cant add it from the beginning.

Comment: @Rasmus: Ah, now I understand, you're keeping the XML up-to-date as your game progresses. I thought this was just for a "save game" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var elements =
    doc
    .Root                       //Ignore the root
    .Element("Playerboard")     //The Playerboard element.
    .Element("Ships")           //There's only one Ships element.
    .Elements("ship")           //Get all the ship elements from Ships.
    .Where(ship => ship.Value == "12_12");  //.Value is a little more explicit but you
                                            //want strings anyway.

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
    element.Add(new XAttribute("Name", "Value")); //Adding your new attribute.
    Console.WriteLine(element); 
}
```

I'm using the lambda syntax because I prefer it (sorry, it just makes it much clearer what I'm doing).

If you only expect one `ship` element to match the given value, you can just use `.Single()` at the end to avoid the collection too.

Comment: Looks good to me, though it doesn;t do any checking for existence - if any of the intermediate nodes doesn't exist, you'll end up with `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @vesan I generally avoid writing error checking on stack overflow answers, it keeps them from getting too long. If the OP knows they have to deal with the potential for missing pieces, I'm sure they can work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
   int x = 12, y = 12;
   var doc =  XDocument.Load("[path of your xml]");

   //Finding the playerboard, by your structure I suppose you have one
   var playerBoard= doc.Descendants("Playerboard").FirstOrDefault();

  var ship = playerBoard.Element("Ships").Elements("ship").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value == x + "_" + y);

  //Adding an attribute to the ship
  ship.Add(new XAttribute("Foo", "Boo"));
```